# Find different word between two strings

Tags: c#, string, comparison

I have a large list of phrases such as

```
"Nola jumped off the cliff"
"Loroy jumped off the cliff"
"Nola jumped off the couch"
"Leroy lept off the couch"
```

I need to find each point in a phrase that is a different word and add that word to a node, which is a list of words that can be used in that position in a phrase. So we would end up with.

```
"Node1(1) Node2(1) off the Node3(1)"
"Node1(2) Node2(1) off the Node3(1)"
...etc
```

Where node 1 represents a list of the names(Nola,Leroy), node2 represents a list of the actions(jumped,lept) and node3 ends up representing the list of locations(cliff,couch)

The idea is to take a list of the phrases, and have it automatically create the nodes and fill it with the words that can be used at that node in a phrase.

So, 1st how would I generate the list of phrase nodes? I haven't been able to figure out how to compare two sentences and see if they are exactly alike minus one word.

2nd once I have the nodes set up, what would be the best way to compare all the combinations of the nodes to come up with new matches? (hope that made sense)

Comment: "I need to find each point in a phrase that is a different word" - different from **what**?

Comment: You can split each string into a string[] by using string.Split() and use the space as a delimiter.  Then compare each string in the resulting arrays.

Comment: You can create "node lists" for each word position in a sentence, run through all samples, and collect your nodes. Then you could collapse all nodes that contain only one word (in your case, nodes at position 3 and 4).

Comment: You might want to start by solving the Longest Common Subsequence problem. I have a sketch of a solution in JavaScript here; it should be easy to adapt to C#: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/21/189974.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice one, I like it. Since you tagged your question with C#, I wrote the answer also in C#.

**A fast way to get the different words between two phrases:**

```
string phrase1 = "Nola jumped off the cliff";
string phrase2 = "Juri jumped off the coach";

//Split phrases into word arrays
var phrase1Words = phrase1.Split(' ');
var phrase2Words = phrase2.Split(' ');

//Find the intersection of the two arrays (find the matching words)
var wordsInPhrase1and2 = phrase1Words.Intersect(phrase2Words);

//The number of words that differ 
int wordDelta = phrase1Words.Count() - wordsInPhrase1and2.Count();

//Find the differing words
var wordsOnlyInPhrase1 = phrase1Words.Except(wordsInPhrase1and2);
var wordsOnlyInPhrase2 = phrase2Words.Except(wordsInPhrase1and2);
```

Instead of matching the elements yourself by looping over and checking each element, you can save yourself time and use the built-in LINQ functions Intersect, Except, etc...

For creating phrases by random, please refer to the answer of NominSim.

Comment: I have never seen intersect before, this is a nifty thing.

Comment: Sorry this took me so long to select as the correct answer, I got sidetracked by a new project and just got back to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another Linq-based solution that generates all possible combinations:

```
var phrases = new List<string> {
           "Nola jumped off the cliff",
           "Loroy jumped off the cliff",
           "Nola jumped off the couch",
           "Leroy lept off the couch"
                           };

var sets = (from p in phrases
            from indexedWord in p.Split(' ').Select((word,idx) => new {idx,word})
            group indexedWord by indexedWord.idx into g
            select g.Select(e => e.word).Distinct()).ToArray();


var allCombos = from w1 in sets[0]
                from w2 in sets[1]
                from w3 in sets[2]
                from w4 in sets[3]
                from w5 in sets[4]
                select String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}.", w1, w2, w3, w4, w5);
```

Doesn't make for the most readable code, but was fun writing. =)

Answer (score 0):

First to generate the list something like this should work:

```
        HashSet<String>[] NodeList = new HashSet<String>[phraseLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < phraseLength; i++)
        {
            NodeList[i] = new HashSet<string>();
        }

        foreach (String phrase in PhraseList)
        {
            string[] phraseStrings = phrase.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < phraseLength; i++)
            {
                if(!NodeList[i].Contains(phraseStrings[i]))
                {
                    NodeList[i].Add(phraseStrings[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then when you create your sentences you can simply traverse the NodeList and pick a String from each node, if you wanted to do it randomly maybe something like this:

```
        String sentence = "";
        foreach (HashSet<String> Node in NodeList)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            sentence += Node.ToArray()[rand.Next(0, Node.Count)];
        }
```

Should note that a HashSet probably isn't the best idea if you need to access it randomly.